# 301 redirect, from index.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web

How can I redirect via 301, from http://mydomain.com/index.php to http://mydomain.com or http://mydomain.com/variable to http://mydomain.com ? I tried this, but doesn't work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^http://mydomain.com/variable [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php$ /
RedirectMatch 301 ^/variable$ /
```